# Symfony Yaml echo variable name

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I want to display the name of the Yaml variables

For translating my yaml files I want to display the variables on the left side and an input field on the right to put the translated string in it.
For example the code is as follows:

```
admin: "Admin"    
admin_cache: "Cache"    
admin_cancel: "Cancel"     
admin_create: "Create"
```

The side on the left should show the variable name (admin_cache)

Can I access these values?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Yaml [sic!] variables".  If you would care to consult the [YAML specification](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), you can see that the word "variable" appears only once, and that is in the scalar `Unknown variable "bar"` in the third document of the example 2.28.

Answer (score 0):

Read them inside your controller, convert them to an array and return to the view. There you can use twig with a for loop to echo index and value.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using twig? Currently I only importet the yaml parser, I don't use the rest of the symfony project.

Comment: Well you can create a string or html yourself. Or you can go for \n and use it in an pre tag.